# Workaround for Clang "exception specification is not available until end of class definition" bug

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, compiler-bug

Given this code:

```
template <typename>
struct Check { constexpr static bool value = true; };

struct A {
    A() noexcept(Check<int>::value) = default;
};
```

Compiling with various versions of GNU `g++` works fine, but it always fails with `clang++` 5.0.1 (both with libstdc++ and libc++):

```
$ g++-4.9.4 test.cpp -c -o test -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
$ g++-5.4.0 test.cpp -c -o test -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
$ g++-6.4.0 test.cpp -c -o test -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
$ g++-7.2.0 test.cpp -c -o test -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
$ clang++ test.cpp -c -o test -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Weverything
test.cpp:2:16: warning: 'constexpr' specifier is incompatible with C++98 [-Wc++98-compat]
struct Check { constexpr static bool value = true; };
            ^
test.cpp:5:39: warning: defaulted function definitions are incompatible with C++98 [-Wc++98-compat]
    A() noexcept(Check<int>::value) = default;
                                    ^
test.cpp:5:9: warning: noexcept specifications are incompatible with C++98 [-Wc++98-compat]
    A() noexcept(Check<int>::value) = default;
        ^
test.cpp:5:5: error: exception specification is not available until end of class definition
    A() noexcept(Check<int>::value) = default;
    ^
test.cpp:5:18: note: in instantiation of template class 'Check<int>' requested here
    A() noexcept(Check<int>::value) = default;
                ^
3 warnings and 1 error generated.
$ clang++ test.cpp -c -o test -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
test.cpp:5:5: error: exception specification is not available until end of class definition
    A() noexcept(Check<int>::value) = default;
    ^
test.cpp:5:18: note: in instantiation of template class 'Check<int>' requested here
    A() noexcept(Check<int>::value) = default;
                ^
1 error generated.
```

On [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) this also seems to work for all versions of GCC newer 4.7.0 (including trunk), but fails for all Clang versions except for Clang 3.4.0, 3.5.0, 3.5.1 and trunk. So this seems like Clang bug.

**Is it possible to work around this bug? How?** Is this bug already tracked somewhere?

### EDIT:

I tracked this bug down to [Clang PR23383](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23383). As of now there is no notice about this being fixed in Clang although it seems to work with Clang trunk in [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/).

This might be related to [PR30860](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30860) (and [C++ DR1330](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1330) as described in [Richard Smith's comment on PR30860](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30860#c1)). It seems that the issue has something to do about when the contents of the `noexcept()` are parsed.

And so it turns out that one obvious workaround is to try to force the compiler to parse these contents elsewhere. One possible solution would be to provide the contents `noexcept()` as a constexpr member constant:

```
template <typename>
struct Check { constexpr static bool value = true; };

struct A {

    A() noexcept(workaround) = default;

private: /* Work around Clang PR23383: */

    static constexpr bool workaround = Check<int>::value;

};
```

Unfortunately, this does not work in all cases, e.g. such as this:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Base { virtual ~Base() noexcept; };

struct OuterClass {

    class InnerDerived: public Base {
    private:
        static constexpr auto const workaround =
                std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<Base>::value;
    public:
        InnerDerived() noexcept(workaround);
    };

    class InnerDerived2: public InnerDerived {
    private:
        static constexpr auto const workaround2 =
                std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<InnerDerived>::value;
    public:
        InnerDerived2() noexcept(workaround2);
    };

};
```

The latter yields the error even when using Clang trunk in Compiler Explorer. **Any ideas why?**